# apache and IP oddities

Tags: apache, tomcat

I installed Apache 2.4 in order to publish a java (Struts2) application using Tomcat 8 as AS.
For a while it worked out well then something happened "strange" (to put it mildly).
By typing "http://localhost/appName" all continues to work out wonderfully.
Typing "http://publicIP/AppName " it opens pop up asking for a password to access the network printer!
The PC address on which they reside, Servers and Application, is 192.168.0.104, the one of the printer is just 193.168.0.103, exactly the previous by the point of view of  the router (working in DHCP mode).
But (I may be *** but not to this extent) to the PC I manually set 104 as the fixed IP (which is still set - and anyway, when I check the Client List on the monitor of the router,  I find right 104 as IP assigned to the PC).
No one has changed the settings to httpd.conf (ServerName is always 104), let alone the various mod_jk.conf or workers.properties or server.xml of Tomcat (so much so that, as I said, typing in the browser the local address all still works)!
...what could possibly have happened?

Comment: Is your apache accessible on the public IP? You can run a virtual host to a specific port and redirect to your application. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your firewall is port forwarding port 80 to the private IP of the printer, rather than the apache server.  The fact that you're getting the printer means the problem is not related to the apache or tomcat configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Something new happened so I think Apache or Tomcat conf is related.

- I restarted the router: at first, typing in the browser "**http:// publicIP/appName**", all was working, after several minutes, typing the app address, it asks me if i wanna download a (unspecified) file and accessing directly to Apache (typing "**http:// publicIP**") it answers "*It works*"!
  Accessing to "**http:// localhost/appName**" anytime all works fine!
- I restarted the router for a second time: accessing to "**http:// publicIP/appName**", error message "`File not found`" and typing "**http:// publicIP**", it asks me the pw to access to an IPcam!  I thinked: "*It's trivial! if it aims for the IPcam... it can't find my app!*"  ("**http:// localhost/appName**" ever all fine, of course!)
- But no: i restarted for a third!   Maybe all ok for several minutes and after: "http://publicIP/appName" returns still a "*File not found*" message but  "http://publicIP" tells me "*It works!*"...!!!

Maybe the connector (or the connector configuration) bears some responsibility for this whole mess?
If my suspicious can have some substance I add the code.
I've a basic manual configuration:
at the end of httpd.conf

```
include "C:/Program Files/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/conf/jk/mod_jk.conf"
```

in mod_jk.conf:

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile "C:/Program Files/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/conf/jk/workers.properties"
```

(JkLogFile, JkLogLevel, JkLogStampFormat, JkOptions, JkRequestLogFormat are also set)

```
JkMount /appName ajp13
JkMount /appName/* ajp13
```

in workers.properties:

```
worker.list=ajp13
worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13.host=localhost
worker.ajp13.port=10009
worker.ajp13.lbfactor=50
worker.ajp13.cachesize=10
worker.ajp13.cache_timeout=600
worker.ajp13.socket_keepalive=1
worker.ajp13.socket_timeout=300
```

and finally, in server.xml:

```
Connector port="10009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"  enableLookups="false" /
```

thank you!

PS - I have another suspicious too: the IPcam remote monitor works on port 80... there may be some relationship? (but that don't explain the download request...)